# Jquery validate con AJAX, Formulario hace submit aunque halla validaciones incorrectas

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario donde hago validaciones con JqueryValidate, el problema es que, aunque halla campos incorrectos, se ejecuta igual el submit del form.

Adjunto el codigo:

```
$('#formvalidate').validate({
    rules: {
      aniosolicitudbeca:{
        required: true,
        solonumeros:true,
        maxlength:4,
        minlength:4,
      },
      aniocarreracursar:{
        required:true,
        solonumeros:true,
        maxlength:2,
      },
      nombrebecario: {
        sololetras:true,
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 30,
      },
      apellidobecario: {
        sololetras:true,
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 30,
      },

      dni:{
        solonumeros: true,
        required: true,
        number:true,
        maxlength: 9,
        minlength:7,
      },
      establecimiento:{
        required: true,
      },
      email:{
        required: true,
        email: true,
        soloemail:true,
      },
      celular:{
        required: true,
        number:true,
        minlength:10,
        maxlength:11,
        solonumeros:true,
      },
      password:{
        required: true,
        minlength:6,
      },
      direccion: {
        required: true,
        minlength:2,
        maxlength:30,
      },
      sexo: {
        required: true,
      },
      calendario: {
        required: true,
      },
      carrera: {
        required: true,
        minlength:3,
        maxlength:30,
      },
      Institucion: {
        required: true,
        minlength:3,
        maxlength:30,
      },
      Localidad_institucion: {
        required: true,
        minlength:3,
        maxlength:30,
      },
      anioscarrera:{
        required: true,
        number:true,
        solonumeros:true,
        maxlength: 3,
      },
      dynamic_field:{
        required:true,
      },
      agree: "required"
    },
    messages: {
      dynamic_field:"req",

      nombrebecario: {
        sololetras: "Ingrese solo letras",
        required: "Por favor ingresa tu nombre completo",
      },
      apellidobecario: {
        sololetras: "Ingrese solo letras",
        required: "Por favor ingresa tu apellido completo",
      },
      establecimiento: {
        required:"Por favor selecciona establecimiento",
      },
      direccion: {
        required:"Por favor ingresa una dirección",
      },
      carrera: {
        required: "Por favor ingresa el nombre de la carrera",
      },
      Institucion: {
        required: "Por favor ingresa el nombre de la institucion",
      },
      Localidad_institucion:{
        required: "Por favor ingresa la localidad",
      },
      sexo: "Por favor selecciona una opción",
      anioscarrera: {
        number: "Ingrese solamente numeros",
        required: "Por favor ingresa la cantidad de años de la carrera",
        solonumeros: "Ingrese solamente numeros",
      },
      password: {
       required: "Por favor ingresa una contraseña",
      },
      dni: {
       required: "Por favor ingresa dni",
       number: "Ingrese solamente numeros",
      },
      celular:{
        required: "Por favor ingresa un celular",
        number: "Ingrese solamente numeros",
        solonumeros: "Ingrese solamente numeros",

      },
      email:{
        required: "Ingrese una direccion de email",
        soloemail: "Ingrese una direccion de email correcta",
        email: "Ingrese una direccion de email correcta",
      },
      calendario: "Por favor selecciona tu fecha de nacimiento",
      select: "Por favor selecciona una localidad",
    },
    errorElement: "em",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element)
    {
      // Add the `help-block` class to the error element
      error.addClass("help-block");
      if (element.prop( "type" ) === "checkbox")
      {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent("label") );
      }
      else
      {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      if($('input[name="tipobeca"]:checked').length == 0){
           alert('Por favor selecciona el tipo de beca');
           return false;
      }
      if ($("#formvalidate").validate().form() == true){
              var action = $(this).attr('action');
              var method = $(this).attr('method');
              var data = new FormData(this);
                $.ajax({
                url: action,
                type: method,
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                  $('#btn-registro-beca').attr('disabled', true);
                  $('#btn-registro-beca').text('Procesando...');
                },
                success: function(resp) {
                  if (!resp.success) {
                    swal({
                            title: 'Error',
                            text: resp.message,
                            type: 'error'
                        });

                        $('#btn-registro-beca').attr('disabled', false);
                      $('#btn-registro-beca').text('Solicitar');
                  } else {
                    swal({
                            title: 'Mensaje',
                            text: resp.message,
                            type: 'success'
                        }).then(function() {
                          location.reload();
                        });
                  }
                },
                error: function(xhr) {
                        swal({
                          title: 'Error',
                          text: xhr.responseText,
                          type: 'error'
                      });

                  $('#btn-registro-beca').attr('disabled', false);
                  $('#btn-registro-beca').text('Solicitar');
                }
              });
              return false;
            }else{
              alert('Algunos campos son incorrectos');
              return false;
            }
        },

  });
```

Es medio largo por que hay varios inputs, pero el problema esta en el **submitHandler**
Agregue un condicional mas **if ($("#formvalidate").validate().form() == true)**  pero aun asi ajax se rie de él jaaaa

Comment: En los ejemplos que he encontrado, es solo .validate() y no .validate().form() .  A propósito, si $("#formvalidate").validate().form() regresa un booleano, no se necesita el == true .

Comment: Pruebo y te aviso

Comment: Listo, era solo ese detalle, gracias!